# Do we need [code] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There is currently a [code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) tag which has 46 questions and a tag wiki excerpt as:

> in this context implies a set of computer programming instructions. Do
>   not use for questions relating to error codes, to enumerations, or for
>   encryption

Is it needed, or does having a tag for the spatial library used in that code (e.g. [arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy), [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis), [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers), etc) make it superfluous, and a candidate for burnination?

Comment: I think we have enough votes to commence the burnination of the [tag:code] tag.

Comment: The [tag:code] tag has been burninated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this tag is redundant. Any question relating to code should have the language tag associated with it.

I vote to burninate.