# Do we need [programming] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There is currently a [programming](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) tag which has 98 questions and a tag wiki excerpt of:

> The act or process of planning or writing a computer program.

Is it needed, or does having a tag for the spatial library used in that programming (e.g. [arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy), [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis), [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers), [arcobjects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcobjects), etc) make it superfluous, and a candidate for burnination?

Comment: Not only the library, but also the program language itself; [tag:python], [tag:R], [tag:vba], etc. See [this answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4366/why-is-the-python-tag-inappropriate-for-a-question-about-shapely/4373#4373) about python, for example.

Comment: [When a programming language tag is used pragmatically](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4374/115) I would agree with the above comment.

Comment: I think we have enough votes to start burninating the [tag:programming] tag.

Comment: The [tag:programming] tag has been burninated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this tag is as redundant as the [**code**](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4631/7424) tag.

Clearly, the language that the person is trying to program in should indicate that it's a programming problem; and they should tag with that language.

I vote to burninate.