# Do we need [scripting] and [automation] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There are currently tags for:

- [scripting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) which has 316 questions and a tag wiki excerpt of:

> `The act of setting up computing instructions, usually stored in a
>   file and interpreted at run time.`

- [automation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automation) which has 160 questions and a tag wiki excerpt and full wiki of:

> `Refers to writing a program or script, or creating a model to perform
>   repetitive and/or complex tasks.`
>
> Automation refers to writing a program or script, or creating a model
>   to perform repetitive and/or complex tasks. It could be a simple, one
>   step task that is done many times such as exporting each group of
>   features with a common attribute value to a separate file; or it may
>   be a complex analysis model with many steps and tools strung together
>   to improve accurate repeatability.

Is either needed, or does having a tag for the scripting library (e.g. [arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy), [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis), etc) or modelling GUI (e.g. [modelbuilder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modelbuilder), [qgis-modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-modeler), etc) make them superfluous, and candidates for burnination?

Comment: I think we have enough votes to start burninating the [tag:automation] and [tag:scripting] tags.

Comment: The [tag:automation] tag has now been burninated.

Comment: The [tag:scripting] tag has now been burninated.

Comment: I re-burninated the [tag:scripting] tag today which I found on three questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per my answers on the [**code**](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4632/7424) tag and the **[programming](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4641/7424)** tag, I feel that both [scripting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) and [automation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automation) are redundant.

Any question relating to scripting should have the scripting language tag associated with it.

I vote to burninate both of them.

Comment: Yes, not only the spatial library (as stated in question), but also the programming language (if wanted).